# Crystal Report: errors when using date range

Tags: crystal-reports, date-range, formula-editor

I am encountering problems with some of the date ranges when using the Formula Editor from the Report->Edit Record Selection Formula screen in Crystal Report (8.2)

For instance,
{SomeTable.someDate} in Aged0To30Days

is giving me the error:
"Different value type of bounds of range."

someDate is a datetime field, and
{SomeTable.someDate} in Aged31To60Days
{SomeTable.someDate} in Aged61To90Days etc
are saying "Formula ok" in the Formula Editor.

If I save the formula under the "Formula Fields":
{SomeTable.someDate} in Aged0To30Days
then it says "Formula ok".  So, the error is only happening in the Report->Edit Record Selection Formula screen.

The problem exists with the following ranges as well:
MonthToDate
YearToDate

but it works for lastFullWeek, Over90Days, WeekToDateFromSun

Any clarification would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess you trying to match a database field which is incompatable with the datatype of the field because whatever you enter in record selection it will go in to database and this is not the case with formula.

Comment: see if this works date({someTable.someDate}) in Aged0To30Days     this is more for my curiosity than anything